# Storing and accessing a snippet of code in a function

Tags: php

In my includes folder I have a function...

```
function storelistingUno() {

$itemnum=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['itemnum']);
$msrp=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['msrp']);
$edprice=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['edprice']); //This value has to be the same as in the HTML form file
$itemtype=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['itemtype']);
$box=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['box']);
$box2=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['box2']);
$box25=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['box25']);
$box3=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['box3']);
$box4=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['box4']);
$box5=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['box5']);
$box6=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['box6']);
$box7=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['box7']);
$box8=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['box8']);
$itemcolor=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['itemcolor']);
$link=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['link']);
$test = "yes!";

}
```

I reference this in about 8 pages and I decided it would be easier to just make a function out of it and only touch this from now on. So I referenced `storelistingUno();` in my code, but I don't think it worked, because I tried to execute `echo $test;` and nothing happened. Do I need to return something?

Thanks.

Comment: the $test isn't part of the code, I sorta just put it in there to see if my code was working or not.

Global does indeed fix my problem, so thank you for that.

Although, I see you guys aren't to fond of that method? I basically just want to have that snippet of code in one place so I can edit it there instead of all 8 pages. I've only been doing php for a few months, and am not really familiar with OOP yet.

any better / proper ways of doing this?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [extract()](http://us.php.net/extract).  You can do something like this:

```
<?php

function getEscapedArray()
{
  $keys = array('itemnum', 'msrp', 'edprice', 'itemtype', 'box', 'box2', 'box25', 'box3', 'box4', 'box5', 'box6', 'box7', 'box8', 'itemcolor', 'link');

  $returnValues = array();
  foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $returnValues[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$key]);
  }

  $returnValues['test'] = 'yes!';

  return $returnValues;

}

extract(getEscapedArray());
echo $test;
```

Although - Its still not the best way to do this.  The best would be to just use the return from that function as the array.

```
$parsedVals = getEscapedArray();
echo $parsedVals["test"];
```

Answer (score 1):

$test is a local variable in that function - you either need to make it global (by putting `global $test;` at the start of the function or using `$GLOBALS['test']` instead of just `$test` or return the value.

Are you thinking of using that function to just escape the values?  Maybe you could make it perform the query too, then you wouldn't have to return / use globals.

Edit:
A different way would be to include the code instead of using a function - not recommended though...

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need these variables a globals

```
function storelistingUno()
{
    $desiredGlobals = array( 
         'itemnum'
        ,'msrp'
        ,'edprice'
        ,'itemtype'
        ,'box'
        ,'box2'
        ,'box25'
        ,'box3'
        ,'box4'
        ,'box5'
        ,'box6'
        ,'box7'
        ,'box8'
        ,'itemcolor'
        ,'link'
    );
    foreach ( $desiredGlobals as $globalName )
    {
        if ( isset( $_POST[$globalName] ) )
        {
            $GLOBALS[$globalName] = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST[$globalName] );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to mark every variable as global before you start to edit them within the function ... this isn't recommented since it's bad coding style but it might help you

```
$test = '';
function foo() {
    global $test;
    $test = 'bar';
}
echo $test; //prints nothing
foo();
echo $test; // prints "bar"
```